# Even CURL function can't scrape some urls

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I'm using CURL to scrape the html from url's. It works great in 80% of the urls I use. But some url's don't seem "scrapeable". For example, when I try to scrape http://www.thefancy.com , it doesn't work. the website keeps loading and at the end it doesn't return a result. the problem is testable at: http://www.itemmized.com/test/test/ this is my code:

```
 if($_POST['submit']) {

 function curl_exec_follow($ch, &$maxredirect = null) {

 $mr = $maxredirect === null ? 5 : intval($maxredirect);

 if (ini_get('open_basedir') == '' && ini_get('safe_mode' == 'Off')) {

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $mr > 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, $mr);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

} else {

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);

if ($mr > 0)
{
  $original_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
  $newurl = $original_url;

  $rch = curl_copy_handle($ch);

  curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
  curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, false);
  do
  {
    curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_URL, $newurl);
    $header = curl_exec($rch);
    if (curl_errno($rch)) {
      $code = 0;
    } else {
      $code = curl_getinfo($rch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
      if ($code == 301 || $code == 302) {
        preg_match('/Location:(.*?)\n/', $header, $matches);
        $newurl = trim(array_pop($matches));

        // if no scheme is present then the new url is a
        // relative path and thus needs some extra care
        if(!preg_match("/^https?:/i", $newurl)){
          $newurl = $original_url . $newurl;
        }
      } else {
        $code = 0;
      }
    }
  } while ($code && --$mr);

  curl_close($rch);

  if (!$mr)
  {
    if ($maxredirect === null)
    trigger_error('Too many redirects.', E_USER_WARNING);
    else
    $maxredirect = 0;

    return false;
  }
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $newurl);
}
 }
return curl_exec($ch);
 }

 $ch = curl_init($_POST['form_url']);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $data = curl_exec_follow($ch);
  curl_close($ch);


  echo $data;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.. hope this helps...

```
<?php


class Curl
{       

public $cookieJar = "";

public function __construct($cookieJarFile = 'cookies.txt') {
    $this->cookieJar = $cookieJarFile;
}

function setup()
{


    $header = array();
    $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
    $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
    $header[] =  "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
    $header[] =  "Connection: keep-alive";
    $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
    $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
    $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank.


    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US; rv:1.8.1.7) Gecko/20070914 Firefox/2.0.0.7');
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieJar); 
    curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieJar);
    curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
}


function get($url)
{ 
    $this->curl = curl_init($url);
    $this->setup();

    return $this->request();
}

function getAll($reg,$str)
{
    preg_match_all($reg,$str,$matches);
    return $matches[1];
}

function postForm($url, $fields, $referer='')
{
    $this->curl = curl_init($url);
    $this->setup();
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    return $this->request();
}

function getInfo($info)
{
    $info = ($info == 'lasturl') ? curl_getinfo($this->curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL) : curl_getinfo($this->curl, $info);
    return $info;
}

function request()
{
    return curl_exec($this->curl);
}
}
{
$curl = new Curl();
$html = $curl->get("http://www.thefancy.com");
echo "$html";
}



?>
```

Comment: Scraping generally encompasses 3 steps:

first you GET or POST your request to a specified URL
next you receive the html that is returned as the response
finally you parse out of that html the text you'd like to scrape.
To accomplish steps 1 and 2, above is a simple php class which uses Curl to fetch webpages using either GET or POST. After you get the HTML back, you just use Regular Expressions to accomplish step 3 by parsing out the text you'd like to scrape.

Comment: Dear Naren,

this class gives me the same result. The script keeps loading and in the end I don't get a result. Step 2 goes wrong with thefancy.com url. He doesn't seem to get the html. If I use another url like http://www.froot.nl for example, than he scrapes it perfectly. Is it possible that it is a server problem? Testable at http://www.itemmized.com/test/test/test.php

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet. The 'FOLLOWLOCATION, true' option cured my scraping woes.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're unable to scrape http://www.thefancy.com because every time you reach the bottom of the page new content is loading so actually you are trying to get an enormous amount of information with the cUrl probably that's where the problem is. You just get a timeout try setting the timeout in php.ini with a larger number and give it a try again. Probably its gona take a while to load but I think this way it's going to work.

Comment: That's not how infinite scroll works. Infinite scroll is implemented via JavaScript. The page itself is still a normal-sized page that the JS simply continually appends more content from new XHR requests to as you scroll down. cUrl is not a browser; it doesn't "scroll" or run JS or make XHR requests.

Comment: About the JS execution it depend on the complexity some of the JS scripts are executed via cUrl without any problems. I was able to execute ajax request with jquery call via cUrl so its not impossible. Anyway you can have a point I don't say I'm absolutely right but I think its worth a try to see the results.

Comment: Either you're not understanding what cUrl is, or you don't understand how infinite scroll works. Infinite scroll is implemented via (client-side, if that was unclear earlier) JavaScript. cUrl is a tool/library simply to make HTTP requests. Simply fetching a page via cUrl will only return the data that the web server serves up. Infinite scroll doesn't ever come into play. And doing `curl http://www.thefancy.com>thefancy.htm` returns a file that's only 46KB and takes less than 275ms to finish downloading. That's hardly enough to time out most PHP/apache setups.

Comment: I wasn't aware how the infinite scroll works and I know how cUrl works. I assume you are right but that doesn't solve the man's problem with the cUrl and the page. Let's think for a different reason than.